# How to dual boot two windows 10 installations while restricting file acess and maintain the ability to easily boot?

Tags: windows, hard-drive, boot, multi-boot, disk-encryption

I have 2 ssd's on my laptop, both of them with different windows 10 instalations. My problem is that I wanted to use one of them for my "less secure programs" but the fact that I can have acess to both of the drives while on either one of them defeats my main objective.

[image: check picture]

Is there anyway that I can secure one or both of these drives and still boot like this? [image: check pic 2]

Am willing to re-install windows on both drives and, or to use another boot option.

Also: Unmounting the drives is not an option.
**I don't mind the ability to maliciously destroy my data on the secure drive, but I do care about file acess if I can just secure that while allowing to easily boot I will be perfectly happy**

Edit: Can you stop assuming that I dont know a goddamn thing about security, or that what i must need is a vm? Just answer the question and stop criticizing. This is something i really need.

Comment: Anything you would do *inside* the OS won't be acceptable because it would then also be reverseable from within the OS, and could therefore be done by a malicious actor from your less-trusted OS.

Comment: Dude i just want to encrypt the "secure one", I know what can be done by malicious acess, I just want to have two installations each on their own drive without them having the ability to acess each others files without breaking encryption

Comment: Why not use a VM instead of a second install?  Isolate the VM, you could even use checkpoints/snapshots and revert back to a pristine state, if needed.

Comment: If it is windows pro editions, then use the built in bitlocker.....https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/security/information-protection/bitlocker/bitlocker-device-encryption-overview-windows-10

Comment: Yea, you're trying to use a more complicated and more problematic "solution" than necessary. Create a VM. Set the rules right to keep things secure, and that will be both simpler AND more secure than the cobbled-together whatchamacallit you're currently trying to string together.

Comment: This is something i really need

Answer (score 0):

I think what you need to look into is a windows feature called Encryping File System (EFS)
You should be able to encrypt each one seperately and they couldn't see each others data.

https://www.isumsoft.com/windows-10/how-to-encrypt-and-decrypt-files-folds-in-windows-10.html

https://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/77130-encrypt-files-folders-efs-windows-10-a.html

Comment: Thanks you for your help, while others were flexing their useless opinions you actually answered the question, cheers for that

Comment: @2windowsbro, I'd recommend a hybrid approach.  Using a EFS setup on a bitlocker'd  install.  which would allow access to less sensitive stuff (even on same drive, allowing the second drive to be backup or extra storage) and largely prevent a compromise of both data sets/stores on EITHER install.